# What's the most efficient way to add a heating effect to a smartwatch prototype?

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, design

Let's say I wanted to add the ability to warm up my wrist to a smart wristband. What component could I add to the wristband that would achieve that? Do I need to add a resistor?

Comment: Not advised. Heating with batteries is the worst way to do it.

Comment: Seems like a great way to run your battery flat in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer:

1. This sounds really dangerous, should there be a problem (i.e.: a short circuit at the wrong place), you could burn your skin or clothes, please be really cautious.
2. Most wearable batteries are not intended for high power applications like this, and can be damaged or destroyed if misused and pose a fire hazard.

Now to answer your question:
You need some type of resistive heating, any other method will be far larger than anything wearable.

You do need to add a resistor, but a single smd or tht resistor will generate a spot-like heat source, resulting in either a hotspot or an inadequate heating solution.

You would be best off with using heater plates, which are pretty much a single track on a flexible board, maybe with adhesive already on the other side. These are pretty common on amazon, and most of them are designed for low voltage.

You could also look for some type of heater tape, like the ones commonly found on water pipes. These are usually designed for voltages 120V and up, yet there are some, which could work with low, 5-12V voltage.

Keep in mind, that this will drain your battery in minutes.